# Pieces written specifically for minikeys

Tags: sheet-music, digital-piano

I never treated minikeys as anything other than a portability trade-off and something used for creating short loops with midi-controller, but recently I got a Yamaha Reface DX and I'm having so much fun with it. After a couple of days however, I've realised that I'm unconsciously using some techniques I never or very rarely use with a regular-sized keyboard, such as:

- I can play 16-semitone intervals with one hand so that I can single-handedly have a sort of bass line.
- I can press (simultaneously or consecutively) two adjacent keys with one finger (something I do more rarely on a big keyboard)
- I more often slide between adjacent keys.

All this makes me rethink minikeys as a slightly different instrument, not to the same extent as electric bass and upright bass, but still different.

My question is - are there any pieces that were composed specifically for playing on minikeys so I can practice and improve techniques that are applicable exclusively/mainly with smaller keyboards.

Comment: How big are your hands? I can barely hit a 9th (14 semitones) on a *regular* piano, and I can hit a 10th fairly comfortably on the smaller keyboard at my sister's place. I also occasionally need to hit adjacent keys simultaneously with my thumb (in some pieces of classical music).

Comment: @Dekkadeci my hands are small) but it 16 semitones, I’ve mistyped it, so thank you for the comment, fixed!

Comment: This isn't exactly a source of compositions ready to play, but something that comes to mind from your question is [8-Bit Keys](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcTt3O4_IW5gnA0c58eXshg) — lots of reviewing new and old toy keyboards, and most videos include music made to fit the particular keyboard. I don't recall a focus on the kinds of techniques you mention, but it might be somewhat informative.

Comment: remember that the original DX needed a very profound sysex editor for any sane person. Apart from that, did you notice that all of Bach's works can be essentially played on a 4 octave keyboard (excluding organ works)

Answer (score 1):

Classically trained pianist and composer **Nahre Sol** specifically uses the *Yamaha Reface CP* in some of her YouTube videos. She has a series where she analyses a genre, often something she wasn't familiar with before, and then writes a piece inspired by it, and performs it on the *Reface*.

The sheet music for some of these pieces can be bought from her website:

- [Pocket Pieces No. 1-5](https://www.nahresol.com/shop-1/pocket-pieces-no-1-5-by-nahre-sol) (Rondo, Fugue, Minimalism, 12-Tone, Ravel)
- [Pocket Pieces No. 6-10](https://www.nahresol.com/shop-1/pocket-pieces-no-6-10-by-nahre-sol) (Funk, Static Flow, Bossa Nova, Blues, Nocturne)

There are additional videos on her YouTube channel, e.g. [this one about Flamenco](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yliXnfftN50&t=13m27s), in which you can see her indeed play two adjacent keys at the same time with her thumb (e.g. at 14 min 12 sec).

I can't immediately find an instance where she stretches more than a ninth, but then her hands are somewhat small, and there isn't much room (or need) for large stretches with ten fingers on a 37-key keyboard anyway.